# Toolbars in Mathematica

Tags: front-end, palettes

*Mathematica* seriously lacks some useful toolbars. I wonder why keeping a totally barebone gui is part of WRI's policy? Would such a feature be so platform-specific that it does not worth design it? I really am clueless here. Palettes are fine, but they don't behave like toolbars or dockers. First of all, I have to write them (which is in itself is not trivial to do, see e.g. [this post on MathGroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/68336b0f8da11d15/8829f7a96c893892?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=syntax%20colouring%20Zachar#8829f7a96c893892)), but then even if I create some, how can I tell them to appear every time I start *Mathematica*, and that they should appear the same place (e.g. toolbar should be below menubar)? It would be nice to have a toolbar where some of the functionality of the menu **and** custom-wrote functions can be accessed easily.

Note that this question is not just about **how to implement it**, but also about **why this was not implemented so far**. If you think that this does not belong here, I am happy to ask it on meta or delete it. For those requiring a specific question for which some coding can be done, here it is:

**Question:**

How to implement a toolbar with buttons like **Restart kernel**, **Delete all output**, **Show memory in use**, **Turn off syntax colouring**, etc. which always starts with *Mathematica* and docks just below the menubar in such a way that when windows are maximized, they do not go behind or cover it?

Comment: Do docked cells not do what you want, apart from being there by default? If yes then I would have thought the real question is "How do I arrange it so that when I start a new nb it has some docked cells by default?". Or are docked cells inappropriate?

Comment: No, because docked cells dock to notebooks and not to the menu bar as far as I understand the concept. This is not the proper way of doing a toolbar. Also, docked cells quickly become redundant if you have multiple notebooks, but you can't use any of their functionality if all notebooks are minimized.

Comment: If all notebooks are minimized, there's no menu bar under which the toolbar could be docked. Or any other place (apart possibly from palettes) where I could imagine putting a toolbar.

Comment: On Linux each window (each notebook) has a menu bar.  A docked cell set for the `$FrontEnd` object would be very similar.  I agree though that it seems like a waste of space. @celtschk Menu bars are part of notebook windows *only* on Linux, not on Windows or Mac.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ok, on Mac the menu bar is always on the top of the screen, for all applications. However I wonder where Mathematica puts the menu bar on Windows, because Windows also has the menu bars on top of the windows.

Comment: @celtschk On top of the screen like on Mac (it's a window with nothing but menus in it).  Yes, it's a bit unusual, but I like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To begin with, if you use menu: `Palettes > Install Palette...` the palette should open in the place it last appeared every time you start *Mathematica*.  I always have two custom palettes visible when I start *Mathematica*:

1. A palette to open one of dozen Notebooks I use frequently
2. [Szabolcs's Paste Tabular Data](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pasting-tabular-data-from-the-web.html)

These admittedly do not "dock" if I move them around, but I have never actually looked for that option so it may be possible.  I know that you *can* make a palette float always-on-top with the option `WindowFloating` (in fact this may be the default; it it switchable with `WindowFloating`).

In answer to *why* I suppose:

1. Because people do such a range of different things with *Mathematica* there is less value in a standard toolbar.
2. Palettes actually do provide for a reasonably similar functionality
3. Actual toolbars are seen as taking up screen space
4. Someone in the FrontEnd GUI department is lazy.  This would also explain the lack of a multi-step Undo. ;-)

Comment: +1, and +lots for the multilevel undo comment

Comment: Point 4 touches something I did not dare to ask here...

Comment: Mathematica 10 does have multiple-level undo (and re-do).

Comment: @murray Yes, and I think we're all grateful for it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you say " I always have two custom palettes visible when I start Mathematica". How do you do that? Specifically, I have installed the Palette from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/changing-default-window-appearance), and I want this to appear whenever I open a notebook. Sorry for off topic.

Comment: @Marius How did you install this palette?  Does it appear in the **Palettes** menu?  If so please try opening the palette using that menu, then close *Mathematica* without first closing the palette.  When you restart it should automatically open.  If it does not let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that was indeed what was needed, thanks! At first the palette only appeared for one notebook, and switching to another notebook made it go away, but after restarting _Mathematica_ it works!

Comment: LOL at "Someone in the FrontEnd GUI department is lazy. This would also explain the lack of a multi-step Undo. ;-)"