# How to make a notebook that will be window maximized when open?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options

I use

```
CreateDocument[cells, opts]
```

to create a notebook.  When the notebook is open, it has a small default windows size and I need to manually maximize it every time.  Is there a good way to have it maximized by default?

Comment: On windows: ctrl+n, then alt+space, x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the option `WindowSize -> Scaled[1]`:

```
CreateDocument["text", WindowSize -> Scaled[1]]
```

Comment: If you want to make it full screen (i.e. without menu bars), then use `WindowSize -> Full`

Comment: @R.M Yes, I wrote `Full` at first, but later thought what OP want might be a maximization with menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read here on MSE, it is not possible to create a default WindowSize for new notebooks. To cope with this efficiently, I've created the following palette which others might find handy as well.

The result looks like this:

[image]

And the full code is:

```
(* Screen sizing buttons *)

fullscreen = 
 Button[Text[Style["Full Screen", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Full}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

autosize = Button[Text[Style["Auto Size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Automatic}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

medsize = Button[Text[Style["Med size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Medium}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowTwoThirds = 
 Button[Text[Style["2/3 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[2/3], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowOneHalf = 
 Button[Text[Style["1/2 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1/2], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

windowOneThird = 
 Button[Text[Style["1/3 width", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1/3], Scaled[.98]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

maxwindow = Button[Text[Style["Max size", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]},
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

maxwidth = Button["\[LeftRightArrow]",
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowSize -> {Scaled[1], Automatic}(*WindowMargins\[Rule]{{0,
   Automatic},{Automatic,0}}*)], BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium]

maxheight = 
 Button[Text[Style["\[UpDownArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowSize -> {Automatic, Scaled[1]}
   (*WindowMargins\[Rule]{{0,Automatic},{Automatic,0}}*)], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

(* Screen movement buttons *)

movetopleft = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["\[UpperLeftArrow] Move", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]],
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movetopright = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["Move \[UpperRightArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movebottomright = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["Move \[LowerRightArrow]", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{Automatic, 0}, {0, Automatic}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

movebottomleft = 
 Button[Text[
   Style["\[LowerLeftArrow] Move", Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]], 
  SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}], 
  BaseStyle -> {"GenericButton", 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]

(* Create palette *)

CreatePalette[Row@{
   (*Grid@{{unlockCell,quitKernel,redColor},{lockCell, "",clearColor}},*)

   Grid@{{fullscreen, maxwindow, autosize}, {windowTwoThirds, windowOneHalf, 
      windowOneThird}},
   Grid@{{maxheight}, {maxwidth}},
   Grid@{{movetopleft,
      movetopright},
     {movebottomleft,
      movebottomright}}
   },
 WindowTitle -> "Screen management"
 ]
```

Once the palette has shown up as a dialog window in Mathematica, you should use (menu) > Palettes > Install palette...  to ensure it is always available under the Palettes menu.

Comment: I think you accidentally posted the same answer in [two places](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77258/5)

Comment: Yes, actually in three, this question as well as [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1641/changing-default-window-appearance/77258#77258) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/opening-new-notebooks-with-a-non-default-window-size/77257#77257). I wasn't quite sure how to deal with this as all the related questions are two to three years old. If you have suggestions for cleaning this up yet preserving my intention to share (and adhere to civil best practice), please do let me know.