# Unable to save changes in Option Inspector from one session to another for the Documentation Center

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

I wanted to change the global option "WindowsSize" to the "large" value using the Option Inspector. It works well for the current session. But then I realize the "Apply" button was greyed and not functional, so I could not save this change for another session.

So my question is: why is the "Apply" button not available in the Option Inspector window? Did I inadvertently mess up something?

My version of *Mathematica* is 9.0.1.and I was trying to change the notebook options of the Documentation Center (making the "WindowsSize" option "Large" by default, because I was obliged to resize it each time I opened it)

I am using OSX

Comment: In the first dropdown menu, change it from "Selection" to "Global Preferences"

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Unfortunately, I tried it before asking and it does not work (neither the scope "Selected Notebook"). I am under OSX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually I got my answer by looking at the question
"[Changing default window appearance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1642/7115)" answers.

It is explained there that to change the default settings of the Documentation Center notebook you have to go to the settings "HelpViewerSettings" and make "Enable" True. The "WindowsSize" option in "Windows Properties" in the "NoteBook Options" does not apply.

Comment: Thanks for researching and answering your own question! :)

Comment: @rm-rf Well, it was not a very interesting question I agree, and since I needed an answer and nobody cared, I had to find it. I posted the answer to help similar situations (I am sure there will be) ... Thank you in any case for your help & time !